# Howto convert to string and read data from TCP packet

Tags: sharppcap

I used sharppcap to capture TCP packets. Now i wanna reconstruct HTTP packet from TCP packets but i don't know how. I read somewhere i can find start of HTTP packet in TCP data... i tried to convert byte[] TCP data to string using this code:
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tcp_pack.Data);
but the string isn't readable. like a binary file that is opened with notepad.
is it because the data is encrypted or code is incorrect?
how can i reconstruct HTTP packet from TCP packets?

Comment: HTTP requests/responses are NOT encrypted unless they go through SSL (HTTPS).
Yes, you can reconstruct the HTTP packets, but I never used sharpcap before, so I'm unable to tell how to exatcly use its functions/methods. Could a C/C++ example help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

try   "Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(tcp_pack.Data)"

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way do to this because you'll need to reconstruct the TCP session in memory.

Essentially, if a message being sent is larger than one packet, it's broken up into multiple packets. Therefore, you'll need to capture those packets, arrange them in the right order, and reassemble the data manually.

If the message is short/simple and doesn't get broken up into multiple parts then you'll need to find out what format the payload is in. Try decoding in ASCII first.